# How to enable Intellisense for .cmake files in VS2017

Tags: visual-studio, cmake, visual-studio-2017, intellisense

According to this [post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/cppblog/cmake-support-in-visual-studio-2017-whats-new-in-the-rc-update/#edit) VS2017 supports color highlighting for both CMakeLists.txt as well as files with .cmake extension. In my projects Intellisense is not scanning and highlighting .cmake files. Is there a setting which needed to be set for this?

Comment: Did you try to use VS2019?

Comment: This actually working. I had to close and re-open VS2017 for the coloring to appear

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Coloring appears after closing and reopening VS2017